# Nested Form Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

My form after getting submitted is not checking the validations on a nested model. Even if I don't put any values in the text field in the form for `:value`, it still saves the contact card then redirects to the `root_path` with the `:notice`. When I enter in good data, the form works the way I expect it and fills the values.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

My controller for the parent model:

```
class ContactCardsController < ApplicationController

  def create

    @contact_card = ContactCard.new(params[:contact_card])

      if @contact_card.save
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Contact Card Added To Directory!"
      else
        redirect_to new_path, alert: "not saved"
      end

  end

  def new
    @directory = Directory.find(params[:directory_id])
    @contact_card_field_templates = @directory.contact_card_field_templates
    @contact_card_fields = []
    @contac_card = nil

    if(cookies[:cc_id].blank?)
      @contact_card = ContactCard.new(directory_id: @directory.id)
      cookies[:cc_id] = @contact_card.id
      if(!user_signed_in?)
        @contact_card_field_templates.each do |ccft|
          @contact_card_fields.push(ContactCardField.new(field_label: ccft.name, required:     ccft.required, contact_card_id: @contact_card.id))
        end
      else
        @contact_card_field_templates.each do |ccft|
          @contact_card_fields.push(User.contact_card_fields.where("field_label = ?", ccft.name).first)
        end
      end
      @contact_card.contact_card_fields = @contact_card_fields
    else
      @contact_card = ContactCard.find(cookies[:cc_id])
      @contact_card_fields = @contact_card.contact_card_fields
    end

  end
end
```

My parent model:

```
class ContactCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :contact_card_fields_attributes, :user_id, :directory_id

  belongs_to :directory
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :contact_card_fields

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_card_fields, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['value'].blank?}
end
```

My child model:

```
class ContactCardField < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :field_label, :required, :value, :user_id, :contact_card_id

  belongs_to :contact_card
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :value

end
```

The 
form I am using:

```
- if @contact_card.errors.any?
  #error-explanation
    h2
      =pluralize @contact_card.errors.count, "error"
      = " prohibited this record from being saved:"
      ul
        - @contact_card.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          li
            =msg

=form_for @contact_card do |f|
  - if !user_signed_in? || !@directory.current_user_admin?(current_user)
    =f.fields_for :contact_card_fields do |builder|
          =builder.label builder.object.field_label
          =builder.text_field :value

    =f.submit "Create Contact Card"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure the `reject_if` is checked first, so if a user adds a `ContactCardField` with an empty `value` it is already rejected, before the save of the contact is attempted, and the save will always work.

Options:

- add a validation on `ContactCard` that at least one `ContactCardField` should be present (if that is required in your case)
- drop the `reject_if` clause of the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and let the validation in the model do its work.

Comment: The second option looks like it worked. Thanks! Before I was creating a contact_card object in the new action which is why it wasn't working before.